# Error log: "client denied by server configuration" but all works fine

Tags: apache-2.4

Centos 7, Apache 2.4, php7, Virtualmin (testing server)

I've read almost all suggested similar questions/answers but still don't realize why httpd log displays these errors despite I don't have any kind of trouble accessing all what is "denied". Html, css, js, imgs all are loaded correctly from browsers.

> [Thu Mar 28 19:16:04.717165 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 13330]
>   [client 192.168.1.251:48510] AH01797: client denied by server
>   configuration: /path-to-/index.php, referer:
>   https://...../index.php?page=4
>
> [Thu Mar 28 19:16:05.034605 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 13330]
>   [client 192.168.1.251:48510] AH01797: client denied by server
>   configuration: /path-to-/overlib/overlib.js, referer:
>   https://.......index.php?page=13
>
> [Thu Mar 28 19:16:05.039902 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 13330]
>   [client 192.168.1.251:48510] AH01797: client denied by server
>   configuration: /path-to-/styles.css, referer:
>   https://......./index.php?page=13
>
> [Thu Mar 28 19:16:05.050694 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 13330]
>   [client 192.168.1.251:48510] AH01797: client denied by server
>   configuration: /path-to-/pat76.gif, referer: https://....../styles.css
>
> [Thu Mar 28 19:16:05.065843 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 2194]
>   [client 192.168.1.251:48512] AH01797: client denied by server
>   configuration: /path-to-/information.png, referer:
>   https://......../index.php?page=13
>
> [Thu Mar 28 19:16:05.118509 2019] [access_compat:error] [pid 7139]
>   [client 192.168.1.251:48514] AH01797: client denied by server
>   configuration: /path-to-/gps.png, referer:
>   https://......./index.php?page=13

Same logs are accessing from non local ip.

These are the settings of this virtual host port 443.  They were set from Virtualmin VH creation.
I guess "allow from all" is not necessary.

```
<Directory /path-to-/public_html>    
Options -Indexes +IncludesNOEXEC +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch +ExecCGI    
allow from all     
AllowOverride All Options=ExecCGI,Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch     
Require all granted    
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php    
AddHandler fcgid-script .php     
AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.0    
AddHandler fcgid-script .php7.3     
FCGIWrapper /path-to-/fcgi-bin/php7.3.fcgi .php    
FCGIWrapper /path-to-/fcgi-bin/php7.0.fcgi .php7.0     
FCGIWrapper /path-to-/fcgi-bin/php7.3.fcgi .php7.3     
</Directory>
```